# Laplace Equation Dirichlet Problem on a disk in the plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

If D be the unit disk then what could be the solution of a problem 
Δu=0 in D,∂u/∂n=cos3θ on ∂D

I have tried using the polar co-ordinates representation to solve this but the boundary seems to be contradicting.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Try to write down your effort so we can help you to debug it. :)

Comment: Since the boundary is non zero(ie.,cos3Q), i am really not sure how to proceed. Please give some hint to proceed

Comment: Have you considered something like $\frac{1}{3}r^3\cos(3\theta)$?

Comment: No, how this will effect the solution

Comment: $\frac{1}{3}r^3\cos(3\theta)=\frac{1}{3}\Re((re^{i\theta})^3)$ is harmonic because is the real part of the holomorphic function $z^3/3$. Check the normal derivative at $r=1$, which is the radial derivative.